# How to show data for only a specific user using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show data related to user but unfortunately it's not working. Currently, when I submit order via my form, every account can see the data. How can I show data for only the specific person who submitted it?

**Database**

Table digitizing_orders table has

```
id | order_name | order_placement | user_id
```

**Digitizingorder Model**

```
class Digitizingorder extends Model
{
   protected $table = "digitizing_orders";
   
   public function user()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
   }
}
```

**User Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   public function digitizing()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Digitizingorder');
   }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{ 
   $data = [
      'digitizings' => Digitizingorder::with('user')->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get()
   ];
   return view('front_end.Customerprofile.digitizing_view_order', $data);
}
```

Comment: you can see particular data after edit or update ?

Comment: yov can get latest entry from db . if you are get data after adding .

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Polices](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#creating-policies)** they can protect controller actions on a *model* from unauthorized users.

After generating and registering the policy you can use its methods like this:

```
class DigitizingorderPolicy
{
/**
 * Determine if the given Model can be Viewed by the user.
 *
 * @param  \App\User  $user
 * @param  \App\Digitizingorder $digitizingorder
 * @return bool
 */
public function view(User $user, Digitizingorder $digitizingorder)
{
    return $user->id === $digitizingorder->user_id;
}
}
```

You can define what's inside the method to satisfy a condition for the user to view a model (e.g privileges or Role).

One of the ways to call it is in the controller:

```
public function show(Request $request, Digitizingorder $digitizingorder )
{
    $this->authorize('view', $digitizingorder);

    // The current user can view the digitizingorder ...
}
```

I suggest reading the docs about it, they're Multiple Ways/Methods to use Polices and might contain something useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

use this in controller

```
$user = \Auth::guard('web')->user();
$data=
    [
        'digitizings'=> $user->digitizing
    ];

    return view('front_end.Customerprofile.digitizing_view_order',$data);
```